# What is the most lightweight data type in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, types

What is the most lightweight data type in Swift. I mean which type takes up the least memory space. Is it (Bool, Int, or Character)? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `MemoryLayout` `enum` to get that information, like `MemoryLayout<Bool>.size`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MemoryLayout` to find that information.

> You can use MemoryLayout as a source of information about a type when allocating or binding memory using raw pointers.

[Apple Documentation - MemoryLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout)

---

```swift
let int8 = MemoryLayout<Int8>.size
let int16 = MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
let int32 = MemoryLayout<Int32>.size
let int64 = MemoryLayout<Int64>.size
let float = MemoryLayout<Float>.size
let double = MemoryLayout<Double>.size
let string = MemoryLayout<String>.size
let char = MemoryLayout<Character>.size
let bool = MemoryLayout<Bool>.size

print("int8 size is: \(int8) byte/s")
print("int16 size is: \(int16) byte/s")
print("int32 size is: \(int32) byte/s")
print("int64 size is: \(int64) byte/s")
print("float size is: \(float) byte/s")
print("double size is: \(double) byte/s")
print("string size is: \(string) byte/s")
print("char size is: \(char) byte/s")
print("bool size is: \(bool) byte/s")
```

**Output is ->**

```
int8 size is: 1 byte/s
int16 size is: 2 byte/s
int32 size is: 4 byte/s
int64 size is: 8 byte/s
float size is: 4 byte/s
double size is: 8 byte/s
string size is: 16 byte/s
char size is: 16 byte/s
bool size is: 1 byte/s
```

---

Also you can find some information about this in [Apple Documentation](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/swift/swift-data-types)

Answer (score 2):

The most lightweight types in Swift are the ones with size of 8 bits (1 byte).

They are many of them in the standard library: `Int8`, `UInt8`, `Bool` and even enumerations (`Enum`) with less that 256 cases.

By construction any `struct` with one property of this type is 1 byte:

```
struct SmallInt {
  var number: Int8
}
```

You can use `MemoryLayout` to get this information. Observe that a class (or indirect enum, Array's) are treated as reference so their size is always 8 bytes (62 bits).